# I can't get the value of a form item when it's inside an ng-template on ionic v6

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I have this form, and when I submit my form I can't get the "fechaAntecedente" value, which is an ion-date time inside an ng-template, thanks in advance.

```
<form #fForm3="ngForm">
.
.
.
 <ion-item button="true" id="open-date-input">
        <ion-label>Fecha</ion-label>
          <ion-text slot="end">{{ dateValue }}</ion-text>
          <ion-popover trigger="open-date-input" show-backdrop="false" >
            <ng-template>
              <ion-datetime
                name="fechaAntecedente"
                presentation="date"
                #popoverDatetime
                (ionChange)="dateValue = formatDate(popoverDatetime.value)"
                [(ngModel)]="form3.fechaAntecedente"
              >
            </ion-datetime>
            </ng-template>
          </ion-popover>
        </ion-item>
.
.
.
</form>
```

If I don't use ng-template I can get the value from the form, but it wouldn't  show the date in overlay

Answer (score 0):

**.html file**

```
<ion-item lines="full" button="true" id="open-date-input">
        <ion-icon name="open-sharp" slot="start" class="detail_icon" color="primary"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label slot="end" class="detail_note"> Date of Purchase </ion-label>
        <ion-label class="detail_title ion-text-wrap">{{ dateValue }}</ion-label>
        <ion-popover trigger="open-date-input" show-backdrop="false">
          <ng-template>
            <ion-datetime #popoverDatetime presentation="date"
              (ionChange)=" dateValue=formatDate(popoverDatetime.value)">
            </ion-datetime>
          </ng-template>
        </ion-popover>
</ion-item>
```

**.ts file**

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'

export class page implements OnInit {

dateValue = '';

constructor( public datepipe: DatePipe ) { }

formatDate(value: string) {
    return this.datepipe.transform(value, 'yyyy-dd-MM');
}

}
```

> Now in your ts file you can get the date using the property dateValue. If you have any doubt just check the date using console.log(this.dateValue) while submiting your form.